# Data is inserting twice in realm database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I am trying to insert values to realm and showing that to RecyclerView if there is no internet connection.If there is internet at the time of installation,it will call webservice.Afterwards data will shown from database on each time.the code is working,But the problem is data is showing repeat in RecyclerView(ie. twice).I can't understand what is the issue.My code is below

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mOnFragmnetSwitch = (Config.OnFragmnetSwitch) getActivity();
    View mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mCategoryListRecyclerView = (ParallaxRecyclerView) mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mTopicsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Topics> topiclist = realm.where(Topics.class).findAll();
    for (Topics s : topiclist) {
        mTopicsArrayList.add(s);
    }

    if (mTopicsArrayList.size() == 0) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new WebserviceCall(HomeFragment.this, AppConstants.Methods.getTopics).execute(new String[]{getSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.DEVICE_ID), getSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.USER_ID)});
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(mFragmentView, "Connet to the internet and try again!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }else {
        setupFunctioning();
    }
    return mFragmentView;
}

private void setupFunctioning() {

    Log.d("count",String.valueOf(count));
    mCategoryListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mCategoryListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mCategoryListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ParallaxRecyclerAdapter(context, HomeFragment.this, mTopicsArrayList));
}

@Override
public void onWebServiceCall(JSONObject mJsonObject, int method) {
    mTopicsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray mJsonTopicArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS_LIST);
        for (int i = 0; i < mJsonTopicArray.length(); i++) {
            final Topics mTopics = new Topics();
            mTopics.setId(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.ID));
            mTopics.setTitle(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS));
            mTopics.setImage(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS_IMAGE));
            mTopics.setDescription(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.DESCRIPTION));

            try {
                realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        realm.copyToRealm(mTopics);
                    }
                });

            } finally {
                if (realm != null) {
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
            mTopicsArrayList.add(mTopics);
        }
        count=1;
        setupFunctioning();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("gggggg", "enter");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("gggggg", "ff");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mOnFragmnetSwitch.loadTitle("Home");
    HomeActivity.fragment = HomeFragment.this;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
}
```

Anyone please help me to find the issue.

Comment: Please tell me what tutorial you followed so that I can write an angry post about it. Thanks

Comment: But you are probably missing a @PrimaryKey annotation and also https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java check this sample for how you're supposed to show data from RealmResults (the easy way)